# Getting an Exception While running a simple JSF?

Tags: java, jsf

When i run my JSF i am getting the following exception...

exception

```
 org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException:
 javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: 
 javax.faces.FacesException: javax.faces.FacesException: Can't instantiate class: ''.
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:522)

org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:398)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:342)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:267)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ExternalContextImpl.java:322)
com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:147)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:87)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:200)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:117)
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:198)
```

**MY JSF code**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="f"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="h"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <f:view>
      <f:loadBundle var="msg" basename="property.menu"/>
      <h:form>
        <h:selectOneMenu id="Name" value="#{myBean.input}">
          <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msg.Arun}" itemValue="#{msg.Arun}"/>
          <f:selectItem itemValue="#{msg.Hari}" itemLabel="#{msg.Hari}"/>
          <f:selectItem itemValue="#{msg.Jeya}" itemLabel="#{msg.Jeya}"/>
          <f:selectItem itemValue="#{msg.Radhika}" itemLabel="#{msg.Radhika}"/>
          <f:selectItem itemValue="#{msg.Karthik}" itemLabel="#{msg.Karthik}"/>
        </h:selectOneMenu>
      </h:form>
    </f:view>
  </body>
</html>
```

**MY faces-config.xml**

```
<faces-config>
  <managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>myBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>mypackage.bean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
  </managed-bean>
</faces-config>
```

**Web.xml**

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: your faces-config.xml and your faces servlet mapping?

Comment: have edited the question.... please check

Comment: so you don't have `<application>`, `<view-handler>`, `<el-resolver>` tags in your faces-config?

Comment: yes, I don't have the above mentioned tags

Comment: what URL are you accessing, and what's the name of your .jsp file?

Comment: My file name is sample.jsp and while runnig it on server i will type it as sample.faces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two flaws:

First in your `faces-config`:

```
<managed-bean-class>mypackage.bean</managed-bean-class>
```

Not sure if this is a typo, but class names **ought** to start with an upper case. This is just the standard [Sun Java Naming Convention](http://java.sun.com/docs/codeconv/html/CodeConventions.doc8.html). so fix it by:

```
<managed-bean-class>mypackage.Bean</managed-bean-class>
```

And rename the *actual* class to `Bean` as well, if necessary. This is however not per-se the cause of this particular problem, but bad practices should be cleaned up as soon as possible ;)

Second in your JSF page:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="Name" value="#{myBean.input}">
```

It says `myBean`, but you only have declared `bean` in faces config.

```
<managed-bean-name>bean</managed-bean-name>
```

Which one is it now? :)

Comment: its Mybean only... While editing the question i made that mistake...i accept the first correction that u have mention..